# What's written on Cook's hand in the film Drive?

Tags: plot-explanation, drive

What's written on Cook's hand in the film Drive? When The Driver is planning the pawn shop robbery with Standard, Cook and Blanche, Cook sends Standard and Blanche away and says to the Driver that this is what you get out of the job, and show's the driver his hand where he has written: ????

I thought it says "F$%^ off", but that doesn't make any sense to me, "F$%^ all" would.  Did I misread it?  I didn't get a chance to re-watch the scene but it's been bothering me since.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It says *Fuck off* because Cook doesn't trust The Kid and thinks The Kid just some overzealous/arrogant punk forcing his way into a world he doesn't understand.

But as we learn, The Kid does understand it very well.

The Kid still gets to go on the job not only because he's doing it for Standard and his wife, showing his arrogance and determination as part of his strengths (instead of the usual weakness it invokes in most characters) but because he presents to Cook that he'll do it *for free*, meaning The Kid can be just more free muscle for Cook's job.

Comment: Then how/why does the kid get to do the job?

Comment: @AidanO - help is always welcome, he is only asking the Cook stay away from Standard's family - which Cook probably thinks is a low price, and that he can always change his mind about anyway as he probably isn't scared of The Kid.  Good question though.